# share only by facebook, twitter, sms Android

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I´m trying to share with Android using the next script:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, subject + text);
this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, sendIntent, 0);
```

This list all app installed on Android.

How can I define the app to share ex: Facebook, Twitter, SMS ? Can I define a order ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lot of plugins are available for this. i found something on https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins.

hope this will work.

but you need to do properly the steps mentioned in the readme file of corresponding plugins.